# Как создать декоратор в классе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, декоратор

Вот упрощенный фрагмент моего кода, который я не понимаю, почему не работает:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    def decorator(self, function):
        function()
        print(self.var+1)

    @decorator
    def fun(self):
        print('*Function*')
```

Python говорит:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Class:
File "test2.py", line 10, in Class
    def fun(self):
TypeError: decorator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'function'
```

Важно, чтобы описание декоратора было внутри класса, так как он использует self.переменные. Разве так нельзя сделать?
А без синтаксического сахара я вообще не понимаю, как это реализовать. Разве что после создания экземпляра класса делать так:

```
cl = Class(2)
cl.fun = cl.decorator(cl.fun)
```

Но тогда теряется смысл использования этого декоратора

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда вы назначаете декоратор внутри класса, вы напрямую обращаетесь к "unbound" функции decorator. Никакого контекста, связанного с инстансом у неё ещё нет. Это не `Class.decorator` и не `Class().decorator`. Поэтому оборачиваемая функция в неё передаётся первым аргументом(попадает в self).
Именно поэтому интерпретатор сообщает о пропущенном параметре `function`

---

Если вы хотите декорировать методы, то можно вынести декоратор из объявления класса:

```
def dec(fn):
    def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
        print(self.var)

    return f


class C:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
    @dec
    def bar(self):
        print('bar')

c = C(42);
c.bar()
```

Хотя, с тем же успехом, можно внести функцию декоратора внутрь класса.
Вызываться она будет всё равно как статическая функция и будет торчать метод объекта, который нельзя вызывать(т.к. при вызове будет передан объект C в качестве fn):

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    def _dec(fn):
        def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
            fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
            print(self.var)

        return f

    @_dec
    def bar(self):
        print('bar')

c = C(42);
c.bar()
```

Comment: `decorator` это `Class.decorator`, ну по крайней мере совпадает по значению, и по крайней мере в этом случае. https://ideone.com/AKXcu6

Comment: Верно, а ещё `Class().decorator.__func__`. Я имел в виду, скорее, что символа Class в момент использования ещё нет.